# Python: write .wav to chosen directory

Tags: python, wave

I can only write .wav files to the current directory

```
fname = 'bassswoon.wav'
wav = wave.open(fname,'w')
wav.writeframes(struct.pack('h', bassswoon))
wav.close()
```

Adding a path to fname, i.e. fname = '/path/to/bassswoon.wav' does not work - the file is written neither in the intended directory ('/path/to/') nor in the working directory.

I don't see anything of use in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html) - is it simply not possible with the wave object? Surely, there must be a way to hack it...

Comment: This question is off-topic. You should post at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: From what I can see, you are not writing, but you are trying to open... I suggest you to use `scipy.io.wavfile` module anyway.

Comment: I thought it may be of interest to other people @ DSP

Comment: @jojek see my edit for the rest of the code. I guess I may be looking at the wrong step in the process... will check scipy.io.wavfile